# Removing old-fashioned finalizers

Tags: c#, memory-management, garbage-collection, finalizer, disposable

In an almost 10 year old system, I've implemented several `IDisposable` implementations. Back in the old days, when I was younger and still foolish, the trend was to implement a finalizer as well:

```
class MyClass: IDisposable
{
    public void Dispose() { Dispose(true); }
    ~MyClass { Dispose(false); }

    private void Dispose(bool bDisposing)
    {
         ... dipose  ...
         if(bDisposing)
             GC.SupressFinalize(this);
    }
}
```

Finally, after almost a decade, this bit us - the Dispose method threw an exception *while being called from the finalizer*, and the process died unexpectedly and without warning.

I want to remove all the finalizers, and keep just the `Dispose` method that will dispose of the resources. Is there *any reason* to keep the finalizers around? None of the objects use unmanaged resources, so I'm pretty sure I won't get resource leaks. Right?

Comment: **the Dispose method threw an exception while being called from the finalizer** : i don't think it's true because you are supressing the `Finalizer` from `Dispose` method when it is called with `true` parameter.

Comment: "None of the objects use unmanaged resources" - Then why did you implement IDisposable in the first place? Also, check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3882804/1974021

Comment: I implement IDisposable to let people write `using(new MyObj())...` and have the cleanup code run when leaving the using block.

Comment: The problem we've encountered was that the constructor of the IDisposable interface threw an exception, so Dispose wasn't called, and the finalizer threw another exception...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general advice on when you need a finalizer is: almost never.  See Eric Lippert's response to the following question:

[When should I create a destructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4898733/when-should-i-create-a-destructor)

Whether your application will have leaks depends upon many things.  However, if you have no unmanaged resources, and you are good about Dispose'ing classes that should be disposed, then you shouldn't have leaks.

On your comment above about running into an issue where a finalizer ran on an object that wasn't fully constructed: this is part of the reason why finalizers can be a dangerous thing.  Writing a correct finalizer is a very difficult thing.  If you really have resources that must always be cleaned up, you should be using a SafeHandle:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.safehandle(v=vs.110).aspx